# Python Webscraping, Beautiful Soup on Business Week to Find Company Year Founded and Location

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to take a Company name from a csv file, and scrape the year founded as well as country where the company is located.  For example,  from the following company, I would want to return "1989" and "Ireland"

http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=allen%20mcguire%20partners

I've been working on this for a while, using SO posts to guide me-- but I can't seem to finish it.  Here is the Main file, which works fine, except for the weird fact that my headers don't seem to be recognized so I have to use the first letter of my header to get the first and only column, but that's fine for my purposes.  My problem is that my webscraping file (printed below the main function here) does not find and subsequently return the values that I want it to.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib
import urllib2
import business_week_test


input_csv = "sample.csv"
output_csv = "BUSINESS_WEEK.csv"

def main():
    with open(input_csv, "rb") as infile:

        input_fields = ("COMPANY_NAME")
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames = input_fields)
        with open(output_csv, "wb") as outfile:
            output_fields = ("COMPANY_NAME","LOCATION", "YEAR_FOUNDED")
            writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = output_fields)
            writer.writerow(dict((h,h) for h in output_fields))
            next(reader)
            first_row = next(reader)
            for next_row in reader:
                search_term = first_row["C"]
                num_words_in_comp_name = first_row["C"].split()
                num_words_in_comp_name = len(num_words_in_comp_name)
                result = business_week_test.bwt(search_term, num_words_in_comp_name)
                first_row["LOCATION"] = result
                writer.writerow(first_row)
                first_row = next_row

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Here is the Webscraping file:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


def bwt(article, length):
    art2 = article.split()
    #print(art2)
    article1 = urllib.quote(article)
    #print(article1)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Google Chrome')]

    if (length == 1):
        link = "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=" + art2[0] 
    elif (length == 2):
        link = "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=" + art2[0] + "%20" + art2[1] 
    elif (length == 3):
        #print(art2[0], art2[1],art2[2])
        link = "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=" + art2[0] + "%20" + art2[1] + "%20" + art2[2] 
    #print(link)

    try:
        opener.open(link)
        #print("here")
    except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
        if err.code == 404 or err.code == 400:
            #print("here", link)
            return "NA"
        else:
            raise

    resource = opener.open(link)
    #print(resource)

    data = resource.read()
    resource.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    #print(soup)
    return soup.find('div',id="bodyContent").p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example code for getting location and the year founded for "A&P Group Limited" company:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

LINK = "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=1716794"
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Google Chrome')]

soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(LINK))

location = soup.find('div', {'itemprop': 'address'}).findAll('p')[-1].text
founded = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': "foundingDate"}).text

print location, founded
```

prints:

```
United Kingdom 1971
```

Hope that helps.